# Enable ZTS on PHP without compiling

Tags: php, pthreads

When I try to install pthreads with PECL, the installation says that I must enable ZTS:

```
configure: error: pthreads requires ZTS, please re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled
```

I've installed PHP with Apt package manager and I don't want to have to replace that install with a self-compiled version.

How can I enable ZTS without manual compiling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot; Zend Thread Safety is a compile time, only, option.

Either find a thread safe package being maintained by someone else, or build yourself.