# How to Install PHP-Zts manually on the Centos 7

Tags: php, pthreads, centos7

I want to install pthreads. When I'm trying to install I will receive this error:

```
checking for ZTS... no

configure: error: pthreads requires ZTS, please re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled
```

now, how I can install Php with enabled Zts?

Comment: "please re-compile PHP with ZTS enabled"—you need to [build from source with `--enable-maintainer-zts`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pthreads.requirements.php), or find a precompiled version that was built that way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable ZTS on PHP without compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24559008/enable-zts-on-php-without-compiling)

Comment: @Chris I want to enable ZTS for install pthreads. but I don't know how to do it. can you send a command list for install pthreads on PHP 7.2?

Comment: What's wrong with the link I provided in my last comment?

Comment: so now I need uninstall PHP and what?

Comment: Please follow both links and read both comments. You either need to build from source with the `--enable-maintainer-zts` option (the documentation explains how to do this) or find a precompiled version and use that instead.

Comment: Now I installed PHP-7.2.26 with enabled ZTS. now, I want to install pthreads i have new error: `make: *** [php_pthreads.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed`.

Comment: "make failed" isn't helpful. All I can say to that is that "make failed". At this point you might want to ask a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There I have a command list for enabling PHP-ZTS (7.2.26):

1- Change installation directory to home:

```
cd ~
```

2- Get PHP version you want:

```
wget http://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.2.26.tar.gz
```

3- Extract PHP file

```
tar zxvf php-7.2.26.tar.gz
```

4- Reconfigure sources

```
cd php-7.2.26 && ./buildconf --force
```

5- Inside the php-7.2.26 folder, run configure command to set what we need:

```
./configure --enable-debug --enable-maintainer-zts --prefix=/usr --with-config-file-path=/etc
```

6- Install PHP (maybe take 5 ~ 10 minutes for installation)

```
make && make install
```

7- Copy configuration file of PHP and add local lib to include path

```
cp php.ini-development /etc/php.ini
```

8- Edit php.ini and set Include_path to be like this:

```
Include_path = “/usr/local/lib/php”
```

Now you have installed php-7.2.26 with **enabled ZTS**.

---

**UPDATE:** Here is new command list for php-8.0 installation with ZTS.

1- Download and unpacking:

```
wget http://www.php.net/distributions/php-8.0.2.tar.gz && tar zxvf php-8.0.2.tar.gz
```

2- My server has need some packages, and you may face something else

```
yum install -y libxml2-devel sqlite-devel
```

3- Configuration (In this step, we're enabling the ZTS)

```
cd php-8.0.2 && ./buildconf --force && ./configure --enable-debug --enable-zts --prefix=/usr --with-config-file-path=/etc
```

4- Installation (This action may take few minutes)

```
make && make install
```

Congratulation now you installed new PHP version with enabled ZTS.

Comment: This works great. I just did this with php 7.3.18 and everything went well. Just have in mind you have to enter php directory right after step 3. Thank you!

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Do you know how to do this for PHP 8.0.2? "--enable-maintainer-zts" is not recognised by ./configure

Comment: @Maz use --enable-zts